# Linux Ubuntu 14.04.1 File Permissions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

im really new to Linux permissions so I would appreciate help with this simple query.

Ubuntu 14.04.1

I have 2 users `root` and `user1`

I have a directory `/var/www/html/gallery`

The directory is `empty`

I would like to create a new group add `root and user1` to that group and make that group have *read, write and delete permissions*(FULL PERMISSIONS), to the directory, `/var/www/html/gallery`

Can someone please help me ?

Thank you.

Comment: Please go with this https://www.linode.com/docs/tools-reference/linux-users-and-groups and http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root is usually not added to any group because root is allowed to do everything he or she wants.

So you have multiple options now:

1) you don't create a group and give the permissons to user1 (simplest solution)

```
chown -R user1:user1 /var/www/html/gallery

chmod -R 700 /var/www/html/gallery
```

2) you create the group anyways and just add one user. that just makes sense when you want to add some more users to the group later

Answer (score 0):

you can use acl for permissions,

```
sudo apt-get install acl

sudo groupadd connoisseurs

sudo usermod -a -G connoisseurs Teddy

sudo setfacl -m g:connoisseurs:rwx /var/www/html/gallery
```

you can vary permissions with r,w,x combinations.